# Как из двух реализаций интерфейса выбрать в рантайме одну реализацию используя класс KeyFilterAttribute из Autofac. c#?

Tags: c#, autofac

Есть такой конструктор класса

```
public HelloConsumer([KeyFilter("EN")] IHello helloService1, [KeyFilter("FR")] IHello helloService2)
```

При помощи подключения фильтра - срабатывают обе реализации IHello

```
builder.RegisterType<HelloConsumer>().As<IHello>().WithAttributeFiltering();
```

Как выбрать одну реализацию в рантайме ?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял - что выбор реализации делается когда ей присваивается атрибут. Выходит - те реализации, которым атрибут не присвоен можно считать "не выбранными" для использования в каком-то месте кода